# MQTT-Broker meets WebServer with Database

Tags: database, web, server, mqtt, iot

I have a question about a combination of a MQTT-Broker and a Webserver.
Please check out the image bellow.

[image: MQTT-Broker <-> WebServer]

Is this a good way to save data from different sensors in a database? 
In the picture the WebServer which communicates with the database is an MQTT Client. The WebServer just subscribe too all topics via #.

Is this scalable? I mean if there are 100.000 sensors out there and all send messages to this one WebServer..?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep a record of all sensor data then it's about the only option (unless you have different client for different sensor types so split things up a bit). The only other option to a seperate client subscribed to `#` would be to use a broker like HiveMQ which has a plugin mechanism that can record all messages in a database.

Also `#` should probably be `sensors/#` in order to skip any other messages that may be on the system.

100,000 sensors isn't the deciding factor here, the rate at which these sensors deliver messages will be the important point as it will determine the actual load.